# Changing default User object for in-memory provider

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony5

I'm just trying to change default `User` object for in-memory provider. Default `User` object is `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User`. But this object doesn't fill my requirements, so i copied that object and added some properties for my requirements then named it as `InMemoryUser` and used it like following:

```
encoders:
    App\Component\Security\Core\User\InMemoryUser: plaintext
```

Then i got the following error when tried to run the app.

```
No encoder has been configured for account "App\Component\Security\Core\User\InMemoryUser"
```

I saw the problem after investigeting about half hour. Symfony is calling `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\InMemoryUserProvider` by default and using `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User` object to create in-memory users in `__construct` method.

Then i tryed to override default `InMemoryUserProvider` as following.

```
services:

    App\Component\Security\Core\User\CustomInMemoryUserProvider:
        decorates: security.user.provider.concrete.api_user_provider
        arguments:
            $users: []  # this should be contains in-memory users defined in the security.yaml but i dont know how to do that.
```

This works fine except a little problem, does not inject `$users` like `InMemoryUserProvider`. Normally, `$users` contains in-memory user list defined in `security.yaml`.

Now, how can i inject `$users` for my `CustomInMemoryUserProvider` and is this a good practice to change `User` object for `InMemoryProvider` ?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

I'm using `symfony 5.1` by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never quite cracked the mystery of properly decorating a service whose constructor gets injected dynamically by a DI extension.

However, in this case, all you really need to do is to change the class of the in memory provider which can be done in a compiler pass in your kernel:

```
# src\Kernel.php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use App\User\InMemoryUserProvider;
class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements CompilerPassInterface
...
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $id = 'security.user.provider.in_memory';
        $container->getDefinition($id)->setClass(InMemoryUserProvider::class);
    }
```

When testing this I originally tried to extend the existing core in memory provider but it uses a private method which can't be overridden.  So I just re-implemented the complete interface

```
namespace App\User;
class InMemoryUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(array $users)
    {
        dump($users); // Confirms get the users from security.yaml
    }
    public function loadUserByUsername(string $username)
    {
        // TODO: Implement loadUserByUsername() method.
        echo "Get User {$username}\n";
    }
```

Confirm it has been wired up as expected:

```
bin/console debug:container | grep UserProv                                               
  App\User\InMemoryUserProvider = App\User\InMemoryUserProvider                                                                   
  Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface = alias for "security.user.provider.concrete.users_in_memory"                                                                                                                    
  security.user.provider.concrete.users_in_memory = App\User\InMemoryUserProvider                                                                   
  security.user.provider.in_memory = App\User\InMemoryUserProvider
```

And made a command just to verify it all worked as expected:

```
class UserProviderCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'user:provider';

    private $userProvider;

    public function __construct(UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        echo "User Provider: " . get_class($this->userProvider) . "\n";
        $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername('xxx');
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Cerad! It's works as i want. obsession and ambition creating that mystery :) Looking too much in the wrong perspective can be a reason to ignore to see another solitions. Like as i do. Thanks again!