# Override vendor class in symfony 3.4

Tags: php, class, symfony, service

I'm using a lib called BotDetect in a symfony 3.4 project and i'd need to modify only the method that finds the config file for the lib.

The class i'm trying to override :

```php
<?php

namespace Captcha\Bundle\CaptchaBundle\Support;
use ...;
final class Path
{
    private function __construct() {}

    // ...
```

So I copied the whole class as it is "final" in src/AppBundle, modified what I needed and tried to declare in services.yml :

```yaml
# config/services.yml

services:
  Captcha\Bundle\CaptchaBundle\Support\Path:
    class: AppBundle\PathOverride
```

It doesn't work, the class from vendor is still used.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722129/changing-default-user-object-for-in-memory-provider/62729515#62729515) might help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you unable to use `captcha.config.botdetect_captcha_path` (assuming I've got the correct library)

Comment: @ChrisHaas I don't think so, the class I want to modify is not a service, I can't find it by typing debug:container, is that a problem for what I want to do ?
Maybe I'm wrong about what you want me to do

Comment: "The class I want to modify" - what I'm saying is, do you _need_ to modify the class in the first place? That library has a config option for overriding the path. Now, if you want to do something more complicated than that, then you'd have to tweak the class possibly. That library appears to be dead as far as I can tell, so instead of hacking away at Symfony, it might just be easier to fork it.

Comment: Indeed, all I want is to modifiy the path, if it is possible, I would appreciate the link please, I did not find anything about this in the doc.

Comment: It looks like you just need to set the config I mentioned to a folder that holds [`/botdetect/CaptchaIncludes.php`](https://github.com/captcha-com/symfony-captcha-bundle/blob/1648d8d1cea4de9da3005b4eebbd33c5cd29ba35/Support/SimpleLibraryLoader.php#L54). I'm just guessing at things by poking through those sources

Comment: @ChrisHaas It works indeed, I defined the path in the parameters.yml, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tristan, can you post that as an answer then? As you say, there isn't any documentation for this on their side, so maybe this will help someone else in the future.